# PyCharm Font color change breaks WarmNeon

Tags: fonts, pycharm, color-scheme

When using the Warmneon color scheme, the "Keyword Argument" color is a dark purple (660099) which is impossible to read (at least for me) against the dark background (404040).

When I try to change just the "Keyword Argument" color, it alters the whole look and feel such as applying the dark background color to every window and button bar.

Editor > Colors & Fonts > Python > Keyword argument

What am I doing wrong ?

PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5
Build #PC-171.4694.67, built on July 3, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.5